# Why is this object undefined? Ruby, Rails, Gmail error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I can't seem to figure out why I am getting the error :

```
2017-01-03T02:57:35.239505+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-01-03T02:57:35.239437 #4]  INFO -- : [89b504ee-5835-4bfa-a3ff-91a3a84549f6]   Parameters: {"id"=>"3"}
2017-01-03T02:57:35.243975+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2017-01-03T02:57:35.243890 #4] DEBUG -- : [89b504ee-5835-4bfa-a3ff-91a3a84549f6]   User Load (1.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 22], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2017-01-03T02:57:35.468562+00:00 app[web.1]: true
2017-01-03T02:57:35.476648+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2017-01-03T02:57:35.476563 #4] DEBUG -- : [89b504ee-5835-4bfa-a3ff-91a3a84549f6]   Blueprint Load (2.7ms)  SELECT  "blueprints".* FROM "blueprints" WHERE "blueprints"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2017-01-03T02:57:35.477654+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-01-03T02:57:35.477582 #4]  INFO -- : [89b504ee-5835-4bfa-a3ff-91a3a84549f6] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 238ms (ActiveRecord: 5.5ms)
2017-01-03T02:57:35.478257+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-01-03T02:57:35.478177 #4] FATAL -- : [89b504ee-5835-4bfa-a3ff-91a3a84549f6]
2017-01-03T02:57:35.478313+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-01-03T02:57:35.478256 #4] FATAL -- : [89b504ee-5835-4bfa-a3ff-91a3a84549f6] Gmail::Client::DeliveryError (Couldn't deliver email: undefined method `subject' for nil:NilClass):
```

For some reason the object @current_blueprint doesn't seem to be working inside of the gmail.deliver block. Am I missing something obvious?

Appreciate any help. Thanks!

```
@current_blueprint = Blueprint.find(params[:id])
mail_status = gmail.deliver! do
  to "email@gmail.com"
  subject @current_blueprint.subject
  html_part do
    content_type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
    body @current_blueprint.body
  end
end
puts mail_status
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try just `current_blueprint` without the `@` sign.

Sometime a library executes a `do end` with a different `self` and can thus not access instance variables, but it should be able to access local variables that are in scope.

Just guessing, let me know whether it works.

Comment: This did it - I knew it had to be something simple, because it executed correctly in the console - thanks much!

Comment: If you're curious why or how this is happening, [this OG writeup by Yehuda Katz](http://yehudakatz.com/2009/11/15/metaprogramming-in-ruby-its-all-about-the-self/) can fill in the details.

Comment: Thanks for the help!